# Expansion problem with \newlistof from tocloft package

Tags: macros, tocloft

I try to write macro(s), say `\foo`, which automatically provides counters and `\listofsomething` like commands for some generated macros, using a `xkeyval` package approach for fine tuning of the generated commands.

I use the `tocloft` package for the counter and `\listofsomething` generation (although I could define some `\@starttoc` like approach by myself, I think)

However, I found expansion problems and no combination of `\expandafter` for `\newlistof` works (I omitted the `\expandafter` statements in the MWE) below.

The code does not complain, but the output is wrong, since using the `generator` macro `\foo` for another macro definition will provide the 'correct' `\listofsomething` command, but the `\listofname` is used from the last one defined, as well all entries go to the same list, which is not wanted.

(Of course, the real code has a lot of features (or will have)), but I boiled it down to a minimum. For example, the macro which contains the `\listofname` will be autogenerated from the `\foo` 2nd arg, if not explicitly given by a key-value, but I've omitted this here)

- I don't suspect `xkeyval` is to blame here (since usage of the key macros outside of it and redefining them to other content will just provide the newest content, not previous ones.
- `\begingroup...\endgroup` would help to keep the namespace clean within in `\foo`, but then the `\listofsomething` macros defined by `\newlistof` are not usable outside of `\foo`
- The formatting of the output of the macro defined by `\foo` is not important here. It's just a small 'header' for testing only at the moment.
- The `\foo` command is designed for `\@onlypreamble` usage, but I omitted this feature here for simplicity.

What's the possible solution of this problem? Or is there a way to `\global` the `\listofsomething` macro afterwards, such that grouping can be used inside `\foo` (perhaps some `\let` etc.?)

---

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xkeyval}

\makeatletter
\define@key{foo}{listofname}{%
  \def\foolistofname{#1}%
}

\define@key{foo}{countername}{%
  \def\foocountername{#1}%
}

\define@key{foo}{listext}{%
  \def\foolistext{#1}%
}


\makeatother

\newcommand{\foo}[2][]{%
\setkeys{foo}{#1}
\newlistof{\foocountername}{\foolistext}{\foolistofname}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname #2\endcsname[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{\foocountername}%
  \addcontentsline{\foolistext}{section}{\csname the\foocountername\endcsname~ ##1}
  {\vspace*{50pt}\noindent\bfseries \large \csname the\foocountername\endcsname~ ##1\normalsize\normalfont}
}
}

\newcommand{\listofmarxbrothersname}{List of Marx Brothers}
\newcommand{\listofstoogesname}{List of the Stooges}

% Define the command \marxbrothers and its \listof...
\foo[listofname={\listofmarxbrothersname},listext=mb,countername={mb}]{marxbrothers}
% Define the command \stooges and its \listof...

\foo[listofname=\expandafter{\listofstoogesname},listext=st,countername={stooges}]{stooges}


\def\foocountername{monty}
\def\foolistext{monty}
\def\foolistofname{List of Monty Pythons}


\newlistof{\foocountername}{\foolistext}{\foolistofname}


\begin{document}
\listofstooges
\listofmb%
\marxbrothers{Groucho}
\marxbrothers{Zeppo}
\marxbrothers{Harpo}
\marxbrothers{Chico}
\marxbrothers{Gummo}


\stooges{Curly}
\stooges{Moe}
\stooges{Larry}



\end{document}
```

The snapshot shows that all entries of go to the same list, that the wrong counter is used and the wrong `List of ....` title. There should be two lists.

[image]

Comment: You have to pass the *expansion* of the `\foo...` macros to the `\newcommand` you do.

Comment: @egreg: You mean to `\marxbrothers` etc.? This would explain the wrong counters etc/wrong list usage, but not the wrong `listof` title

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you do with

```
\foo[listofname={\listofmarxbrothersname},listext=mb,countername={mb}]{marxbrothers}
```

is essentially

```
\newlistof{\foocountername}{\foolistext}{\foolistofname}
\newcommand\marxbrothers[1]{%
   \addcontentsline{\foolistext}{section}{\csname the\foocountername\endcsname~##1}%
  ...%
}
```

which is certainly not what you want, because `\marxbrothers` will use the *current* value of `\foocountername` and so on.

You'd need a gigantic `\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup...}\x` trick, which is very cumbersome to write, with many `\expandafter` and `\noexpand` in strategic places. Not something I'd want to do.

Here's a much simpler implementation with `expl3`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { christian/foo }
 {
  listofname .tl_set:N = \l_foo_listofname_tl,
  countername .tl_set:N = \l_foo_countername_tl,
  listext .tl_set:N = \l_foo_listext_tl,
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{O{}m}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { christian/foo } { #1 }
  \__foo_create_commands:nVVV {#2} \l_foo_countername_tl \l_foo_listext_tl \l_foo_listofname_tl
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__foo_create_commands:nnnn
 {
  \newlistof{#2}{#3}{#4}
  \cs_new_protected:cpn { #1 } ##1
   {
    \refstepcounter{#2}
    \addcontentsline{#3}{section}{\use:c{the#2}~##1}
    \group_begin:
    \par
    \vspace*{20pt}
    \noindent\large\bfseries\use:c{the#2}~##1\par
    \group_end:
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__foo_create_commands:nnnn { nVVV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\listofmarxbrothersname}{List of Marx Brothers}
\newcommand{\listofstoogesname}{List of the Stooges}

% Define the command \marxbrothers and its \listof...
\foo[listofname={\listofmarxbrothersname},listext=mb,countername={mb}]{marxbrothers}
% Define the command \stooges and its \listof...
\foo[listofname=\listofstoogesname,listext=st,countername={stooges}]{stooges}

\begin{document}

\listofstooges
\listofmb

\marxbrothers{Groucho}
\marxbrothers{Zeppo}
\marxbrothers{Harpo}
\marxbrothers{Chico}
\marxbrothers{Gummo}

\stooges{Curly}
\stooges{Moe}
\stooges{Larry}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In my opinion, `\foo` should have two mandatory arguments and possibly the keys should be marked as required, because you need all three of them when you define a new list with a new command.

Comment: I think, I should really learn LaTeX3 now ;-)  The actual `\foo` command would have two mandatory commands is actually a `\NewDocumentCommand` already, but I reduced it for the MWE. I omitted the explicit setting of keys to provoke errors if not specified